# c++ destructor calls a delete operator?

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

Why does my MSVC12 compiler not like this?

```
#include <new>

class thing
{
public:
    thing() {}
    ~thing() {}
    static void operator delete(void* ptr) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    int g;
    void* p = &g;
    thing* t1 = new(p) thing();
    t1->~thing();

    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is oddly on the closing brace of main():

Error   2   error C2280: 'void thing::operator delete(void *)' : attempting to reference a deleted function

If I comment out the explicit destructor call, the error goes away, implying that the explicit destructor call is trying to call operator delete(void*). This does not make intuitive sense. As you can probably see from the code here, I've already managed my own memory, and I don't want anyone to call delete on thing ever.

Comment: It [compiles and works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0c0ca91f45c3887) in gcc5, as it should. What happens if you compile in release mode?

Comment: [cpp.sh/3mqd](http://cpp.sh/3mqd) - gcc works fine

Comment: Release build has the same error. Seems this is a compiler bug?

Comment: Same error for MSVC2015 !

Comment: Well, at least it's not really calling thing::operator delete. removing = delete and inserting a printf() in there doesn't execute.

Comment: Check `sizeof(thing) <= sizeof g` , the `new` may write out of bounds otherwise. Also, can you reproduce the bug using `void *p = ::operator new(sizeof(thing));` , instead of using an `int` variable?

Comment: I would guess that it has to do with the deleting destructor, one of two helper methods MSVC silently adds to classes with non-trivial destructors to aid with calls to `operator delete()` (by acting as a wrapper for the `delete` and destructor calls).  For some reason, it would appear that in this particular situation, placement new makes it try to use that method instead of using the destructor directly.  I may be wrong, but that's the only logical connection I can think of between `operator delete()` and `~T()` in MSVC, when the object isn't explicitly `delete`d.

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely a bug 
since by simply replacing the virtual call to the destructor with a nonvirtual one: `t1->thing::~thing()` it works. But obviously in this case there is no inheritance involved and therefore no difference between the two forms.

You can try and submit the bug through [the Microsoft Connect site for VS](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)

Comment: The destructor is not virtual

Comment: It's not, but a call that uses the explicit method name is called a nonvirtual call.

Answer (score 3):

The consensus in this thread is that this is a compiler bug unique to MSVC++. I have reported this to Microsoft here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2511044

UPDATE: MS reports that the issue is resolved and will be available in the next VS update.